# Scala & Circe: JSON encoding with optional fields

Tags: json, scala, encoding, circe

I am trying to use Circe to do some JSON encoding as follows:

```
import io.circe.{Encoder, Json}
import io.circe.syntax._

case class Person(name: String, nickname: Option[String] = None)

object EncodingTest extends App {
  val persons = List (Person("John", None), Person("Tania", Some("Awesome")))

  implicit val encodePerson: Encoder[Person] = (p: Person) => {
    Json.obj(
      ("name", Json.fromString(p.name)),
      ("nickname", Json.fromString(p.nickname.getOrElse(""))) // <- Problem is here
    )
  }

  for(person <- persons)
    println(person.asJson)
}
```

Ideally, I would like to have the following output:

```
{"name":"John"}
{"name":"Tania","nickname":"Awesome"}
```

How can I make the encoder skip the `nickname` field in case the field value is `None`?

Comment: You can use auto derivation, so circe will create `Encoder` and `Decoder` for your case class for you with desired behavior of absent field: https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/auto-derivation.html

Comment: @IvanKurchenko thanks for your comment! This will work in my actual use case (i.e. not the over-simplified example I pasted in the top), where I am defining custom types but in the end it all boils down to basic types that can be handled by auto-derivation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to define custom encoders and not rely on semiauto the following works

```
import io.circe.{Encoder, Json}
import io.circe.syntax._

object CirceOptional extends App {

  case class Person(name: String, nickname: Option[String] = None)

  val encodePerson: Encoder[Person] = (p: Person) => {
    Json.obj(("name", p.name.asJson), ("nickname", p.nickname.asJson))
  }

  implicit val noNullEncoder: Encoder[Person] = encodePerson.mapJson(_.dropNullValues)

  val persons = List (Person("John", None), Person("Tania", Some("Awesome")))

  for(person <- persons)
    println(person.asJson)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easy way would be to just collect fields you are interested in

```
Json.obj(List(
  ("name", Some(Json.fromString(p.name))),
  ("nickname", p.nickname.map(Json.fromString))
).collect {
  case (name, Some(value)) => name -> value
}: _*)
```

More automatic way to get what you want:

```
import io.circe.generic.semiauto._
implicit val encodePerson: Encoder[Person] = deriveEncoder
person.asJson.dropNullValues
```